# using .htaccess inside a folder subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a sub directory and with .htaccess , i have index.php and action.php ,
actually when i submit **a option** must redirect to and post in action.php,once again the action.php must post in index.php as  **www.yoursitename/subdirectiry/product1** using **header()**

for this i have to rule in **.htaccess** inside **subdirectory**,  i have rewrritten as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?product=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?product=$1
```

**it works well in my wamp server**,but didn't work in my **000webhost account** **subdirectory**.

any help guys!
thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /subdirectory`

Comment: @gerald sir could you explain well ... i'm little new to this .htaccess pls!